# Table floating automatically

Tags: tables, floats

I'm trying to force table placement in a specific section created with this purpose, however the table automatically goes to the next page whenever I try to insert it.

I'm using the repUERJ template available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bpqdkmgxznvh#/11388571/).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,fleqn]{repUERJ}        
\usepackage{float}
```

Table:

```
\begin{table}[H] {12cm}
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \textbf{Variável}                                                                                                                                               & \textbf{Fonte} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I  }                                                                                                             & SEV           \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{P }                                                                                                                              & IBGE           \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A}                                                                                                                         & IBGE           \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}T = Intensidade Energética\\ O\end{tabular}} & IBGE e BEN     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

PS: this template does not allow to avoid inserting the width of the table in `{}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you absolutely don't want your table to float, don't use the `table` environment (only `tabular`). In this case, you will have to resort to other things to have caption or centering, if you need those, but the `tabular` by itself does not float.

Comment: A float always uses \columnwidth or \textwidth (depending on the type of float).

Comment: you have used [H] so disable all of latex's float mechanism and the figure just comes where you place it. If it is in teh wrong place in the output you need to move it in the source, that's what `[H]` means. (as noted in a comment on your last question `{12cm}` just typesets 12cm at the top of the figure, presumably you want to delete that.

Comment: This is the same (partial) example and same question as your previous question. As noted in the comments there you need to provide an example if there is something that you think is not working.